# What are .LFB .LBB .LBE .LVL .loc in the compiler generated assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

When I look into the assembly code generated by GCC, there are many lines begining with `.LBB` and a number. It seems to that they are not instructions of operations. More like marking something of the file or what.

**What are `.LFB`, .`LVL`, `LBB`, `LBE` etc are in the compiler generated assembly code?**
Does the .loc means "line of code". Do those lines just indicate `symbol table`?

Here is a piece of code,

```
main:
.LFB1:
  .loc 1 8 0
  .cfi_startproc
.LVL2:
.LBB4:
.LBB5:
  .loc 1 2 0
  movsd b(%rip), %xmm0
.LBE5:
.LBE4:
  .loc 1 10 0
  xorl  %eax, %eax
.LBB7:
.LBB6:
  .loc 1 2 0
  mulsd a(%rip), %xmm0
.LBE6:
.LBE7:
  .loc 1 9 0
  movsd %xmm0, a(%rip)
.LVL3:
  .loc 1 10 0
  ret
  .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Those looks to be labels.

Comment: Can you also give us the input C code and the exact compilation command?

Answer (score 29):

**.loc**

As mentioned by Ferruccio `.loc` is a debugging directive, and it only appears in GCC 4.8.2 if you tell the compiler to generate debugging information with `-ggdb`.

`.loc` is documented at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/as/LNS-directives.html#LNS-directives and the exact output depends on the debug data format (DWARF2, etc.).

The other are labels.

**.L prefix**

GCC uses the `.L` for local labels.

GAS will not generate any symbols on the compiled output by default as documented at: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/as/Symbol-Names.html

> A local symbol is any symbol beginning with certain local label prefixes. By default, the local label prefix is `.L' for ELF systems
>
> Local symbols are defined and used within the assembler, but they are normally not saved in object files. Thus, they are not visible when debugging. You may use the `-L' option (see Include Local Symbols: -L) to retain the local symbols in the object files.

So if you compile with: `as -c a.S`, `nm a.o` does not show those labels at all.

This only makes sense because you cannot generate such labels from a C program.

There are also options that manage it like:

- `man as`: `--keep-locals`
- `man ld`: `--discard-all`

This seems to be a GCC toolchain specific convention, not part an ELF ABI nor NASM.

Furthermore, both NASM and GAS use the convention that labels that start with a period (except `.L` in GAS) generate local symbols: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9 which are still present on the output but not used across object files.

**Suffixes**

The suffixes you mention all appear to be debugging related, as they are all defined under [gcc/dwarf2out.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/dwarf2out.c) on GCC 4.8.2 and [DWARF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) is a major debugging information format for ELF:

```
#define FUNC_BEGIN_LABEL  "LFB"
#define FUNC_END_LABEL    "LFE"
#define BLOCK_BEGIN_LABEL "LBB"
#define BLOCK_END_LABEL   "LBE"
ASM_GENERATE_INTERNAL_LABEL (loclabel, "LVL", loclabel_num);
```

From my experiments, some of them are generated only with `gcc -g`, others even without `g`.

Once we have those define names, it is easy to generate C code that generates them to see what they mean:

- `LFB` and `LFE` are generated at the beginning and end of functions
- `LBB` and `LBE` were generated by the following code with `gcc -g` on internal function block scopes:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main() {
      int i = 0;
      {
          int i = 1;
          printf("%d\n", i);
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- `LVL`: TODO I was not able to easily understand it. We'd need to interpret the source some more.

Comment: Might be worth noting that `.loc` apparently stands for `Line Of Code`. All info it contains is related to the given line.

Comment: Updated link to dwarfout [gcc/dwarf2out.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/dwarf2out.c)

Comment: @Waqar thanks. I wonder if they actually deleted tags (criminal!) or if I just copied it wrong originally.

Answer (score 4):

The `.loc` directive is used to indicate the corresponding line of source code.
It indicates the file number, line number and column number of the corresponding source code.

The rest look like labels.

Comment: Do you know the reason for lots of labels per line of actual code? (Though I suppose they may come from boilerplate fragments of code, and 'cleaning up' is considered unnecessary and/or expensive.)