# Assembly: how to generate .section .debug_info?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-64, debug-symbols

This is more precise version of this question: [Creating debug symbols for gdb manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242650/creating-debug-symbols-for-gdb-manually).
I generate asm code for my language, and I want an ability to watch variables.
AFAIK, what allows to do this is defined after

```
.section        .debug_info,"",@progbits
```

**Question**: how can I generate `.section .debug_info` for DWARF (since my system is Linux; but actually I'm fine with anything that works)?
Is there a documentation for this section somewhere?

Let's for concreteness talk about this program:

```
int sum(int a, int b) { 
    return a+b;
}
```

The generated asm can be seen here (x86-64 gcc 7.3): https://godbolt.org/z/ooTuuO
The part of it, which, I think, I need:

```
.Ldebug_info0:
        .long   0x6f
        .value  0x4
        .long   .Ldebug_abbrev0
        .byte   0x8
        .uleb128 0x1
        .long   .LASF0
        .byte   0x4
        .long   .LASF1
        .long   .LASF2
        .quad   .Ltext0
        .quad   .Letext0-.Ltext0
        .long   .Ldebug_line0
        .uleb128 0x2
        .string "sum"
        .byte   0x1
        .byte   0x1
        .long   .LASF3
        .long   0x6b
        .quad   .LFB0
        .quad   .LFE0-.LFB0
        .uleb128 0x1
        .byte   0x9c
        .long   0x6b
        .uleb128 0x3
        .string "a"
        .byte   0x1
        .byte   0x1
        .long   0x6b
        .uleb128 0x2
        .byte   0x91
        .sleb128 -20
        .uleb128 0x3
        .string "b"
        .byte   0x1
        .byte   0x1
        .long   0x6b
        .uleb128 0x2
        .byte   0x91
        .sleb128 -24
        .byte   0
        .uleb128 0x4
        .byte   0x4
        .byte   0x5
        .string "int"
        .byte   0
```

I can see variable names, but I don't understand anything aside from that. What I've tried to look at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212164/2956272 . It contains some useful info (such as `.loc` and `.LFB, .LFE` labels meaning), but not enough to understand the contents of the section.
- https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/as/Symbols.html - There is some info about symbols, but it's too general
- Dwarf documentation: http://dwarfstd.org/doc/DWARF4.pdf . Of course, I only skimmed through it, but I didn't see anything that matches what I see in asm. As I understand, there is almost direct translation from what I see to Dwarf, but I don't know how it's done.
- And many others.

In other words, I was not able to find documentation for this section. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: It's DWARF debugging information, so documentation is in the DWARF standard you linked. You'll actually need to read it. The names of the symbols `.LFE0`, `.LASF0`, etc. are arbitrary, you can pick your own names when generating your own debugging info. For documentation on what the assembler directives. `.long`, `.uleb128`, etc. do you'll need to read the GNU Assembler documentation, but it should be obvious once you've read and understood the DWARF documentation.

Comment: @RossRidge, Thank you! I've just run `readelf --debug-dump=info a.out` and feel myself pretty stupid. I've a question about `DW_AT_language` (source language), if you don't mind. It has some predefined set of languages and my language actually doesn't even look like them. Does it matter? Will I be able to use symbol information for my language? I didn't understood from relevant sections what exactly this attribute affects.

Comment: Never mind. It seems it's for type specification: `A type unit entry may have a DW_AT_language attribute...`